# Can't get environmental variables set in .bash_profile on Mac Maverick out in Java

Tags: java, macos, environment

I set a variable in .bash_profile and .bashrc

export WINDUP_HOME=/Users/robbg/git/windup/windup-distribution-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

export PATH=$PATH:$WINDUP_HOME

Then I use this code to try to extract it.

```
    String windupHome = System.getenv("WINDUP_HOME");
```

But this retrieves null every time.

The variable does show up whenever I type env into a terminal window.  What is wrong?

Comment: And how do you run your Java program? Have you closed and reopened your session after you have set these variables?

Comment: You may be running under a shell other than bash?  Try `System.out.println("--> "+System.getenv("SHELL"));`